# terminal remote repo has wrong url

Tags: git, terminal

I have not really used the terminal much, but I want to push my project to a remote repo on bitbucket. After I stage and commit everything, I put:

```
Tammys-MacBook-Pro:Pathogen calebbertrand$ git remote add origin https://CalebBertrand@bitbucket.org/CalebBertrand/pathogen.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Tammys-MacBook-Pro:Pathogen calebbertrand$ git push -u origin --all

Password for 'https://Awesomeninjawarrior@bitbucket.org': 
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://Awesomeninjawarrior@bitbucket.org/Awesomeninjawarrior/pathogen.git/'
```

As you can see, the Terminal thinks I want to push to Awesomeninjawarrior@bitbucket.org, but actually I want to push to CalebBertrand@bitbucket.org. AwesomeNinjawarrior was my old username, but then I changed it on the bitbucket website. How do I tell the terminal to push to the right url?

Comment: what do you get with git remote -v

Comment: Git knows you really want to be an AwesomeNinjaWarrior.

Comment: Thx guys, that worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The `git remote add` didn't work and you got an error.

```
$ git remote add origin https://CalebBertrand@bitbucket.org/CalebBertrand/pathogen.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

`fatal: remote origin already exists.` says you tried to add a new remote, but it already exists. You already have a remote named origin. "Fatal" means the command didn't work.

Instead you can change an existing remote with `git remote set-url origin https://CalebBertrand@bitbucket.org/CalebBertrand/pathogen.git`.

You can also list your remotes with `git remote -v`.

Read [*Working With Remotes*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in the Pro Git book.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempted to add the remote, you got an error back, that the origin already existed. Therefore that command had a net effect of doing nothing.

```
$ git remote add origin https://CalebBertrand@bitbucket.org/CalebBertrand/pathogen.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Since the remote already exists, to set its URL you need to modify it instead.

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://CalebBertrand@bitbucket.org/CalebBertrand/pathogen.git
```